# Call Proceduta Cross DB in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, cross-database

I want to call procedures cross databases in PostgreSql
I found dblink, but I'm trying to understand if it's also possible to call procedures with it
If not, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [db_link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html) for this. You can execute any piece of SQL over db_link.

If you only need access to different tables on these external databases, you could use a foreign table as well. For this you have to install the [postgres_fdw-extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html).

Comment: what is the syntax